# Overlay images on Google Maps via Google Maps Api V3 taken by Drone with Camera Direction downward

Tags: javascript, google-maps, image-processing, google-maps-api-3, projection

Is this possible to Overlay the images on Google Maps with Google Maps Api V3 in the correct projection?

I have images taken by drone and I am able to overlay them with the approx bounds, but the images are not displaying in the correct angle as compared with Google Maps.

The images are taken with different angles. See the attached images.

[image: Full area]

[image: Projection of small images.]

[image: Small images overlay]

[image: Google Map without overlay of images.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use css rotate on each element to line things up.

A better solution would be to take the images with something like  PrecisionMapper to control your drone, so they all line up with each other.

https://www.precisionhawk.com/precisionmapper

Comment: How do I know which way to rotate?